# Why did a bulge appear after I mounted a wine rack to my wall?

Tags: drywall, drill, mounting, studs

I'm new to 'DIY-ing' and this evening I mounted a wooden wine rack to my wall. I used a stud finder, made my marks and when I drilled the hole on the left hand side it felt like.. nothing.. no stud. I shifted the drilled a little to the left and tried again, still nothing. I tried once more, shifted the drill a little more left and I got the stud. No issues with the stud on the right hand side. Hung the wine rack and it looks perfect. Pretty sturdy too.

A couple hours later a 'bubble' appeared.. Its weird, it looks like a bubble from when water is trapped behind paint but when I touched it, it was hard, almost like the drywall raised, but only in that one area on the left hand side.

Does anyone know what this could be? All help is greatly appreciated.

Thank-you.
[image]

Comment: If this bubble is over a stud, it would probably be a 'nail pop'. A drywall nail has pushed out under the tape and bedding. This could be due to the original drywall having had a small air gap between the drywall and the stud. When you screwed down the wine rack you closed this gap and forced the drywall away from the head of the nail causing it to press out on the tape joint.

Comment: @JimStewart If that was an answer, I'd vote it up.

Comment: @JimStewart Is that what a nail pop looks like? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: A really professional fix is beyond *me*, and way too much trouble to ever get to the top of my to do list.  I'd cover it with an addition of trim  to the wine rack. Of course, with trim made up to cover it, but not installed, I might try to fix it by cutting it open with a razor, driving in the screw and then gluing down the flap with Elmer's. Then I would see how bad it looked and then put the covering trim on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a textbook screw pop there, where the drywall hanger didn't run the screw in snug, leaving a gap behind the drywall. When you mounted your rack, the drywall was pressed tight and the protruding screw forced the surface out.

The fix is do drive the screw in (through the joint compound) and repair the damage. Even if you remove your wine rack the outline of the bulge will probably remain visible.

Fortunately, you have smooth walls. I'd pull down the rack, run the screw in tight (remove it or drive it through with a hammer and set if it spins free), cut out the loose material, and skim with drywall joint compound. It will probably take several applications, with dry time in between, due to shrinkage. Sand, paint, and hang your rack again.

Of course, you could also drive the screw in, then raise your wine rack a bit and pretend it never happened. :)

Comment: That's a pretty big "bubble" for a screw/nail pop, no? Aren't nail/screw pops usually just about the size of the nail/screw head?

Comment: Not if they pull paper with them. Could also be debris behind the drywall. It amounts to the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, I guess a screw has a better chance of grabbing the surrounding material, whereas a nail would likely not.

Comment: +1 The screw could also have popped, if it was ran too deep, and not removed/replaced; or they hit a knot, and tried to beat it in (it happens).

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest fix is to skim around that bubble to feather it out or hide it.   The drywall sheet has been compromised, trying to get the bubble or pop to set back down will not work.  Drywall is crumbly in the middle so once the integrity of a piece is compromised it is shot.  Kinda like cardboard.

Take a 6” knife w/ a fair ant of compound on it and set one corner of the knife on the edge and skim in a circle around it giving you a “ramp”.  Let dry and repeat until it appears flat.

Overall painting and drywall is an illusion no wall or surface is actually flat- it just appears that way

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Comment: I disagree with this answer. Skimming is a temporary fix that will fail as soon as the wine rack is removed, allowing the drywall to move again. I've seen it a hundred times, with layers of "repairs" amounting to a mess. The only good fix is to run a pair of screws in flanking the popped screw, making sure they hit framing, and remove (or tighten) the faulty screw. Once the drywall is pulled tight to the framing all will be well.

Comment: I can’t measure the bulge but I’m guessing the edge of the bulge is decently outside of the studs (16” on center, 2x4 is actually 1.75”) I’m also doubting the wine racks will be removed anytime soon, so “hiding” it sounds to me the best option for a DIY.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that's a pretty big "nail pop". Be careful you might have tightened an intensional air gap that was  a judgement call by the original hanger. Reasons for this would be like if there was a build up of items like cut off or capped piping, metal strong ties and nails, bolts, or steel plate type supports or even one of those nasty door bell transformer things you always see half buried in taping mud in the wierdest spot in a garage or closet or something. I hang dry wall for a living and I would fix it by removing the popped out part and float over it  real good with an excessive amount of joint compound and make it flat and even by sanding the excess down. But becareful adding screws around the area. If it's more than a nail pop it could keep happening over the area. It's not likely but it is possible. You might try and see if the popped out area seems magnetic at all. If it is a nail pop the nail would reveal a small tiny area of magnetism or be too deep to react with the magnet. If the whole area seems to yield magnetic areas then it's more than a nail pop and anything could be under there. Like someone suggested you could always hide it by adjusting your racks location. It is more work than it's worth most of the time but it depends on the resident and the circle of friends who might see it really. In other words if it's in a dining or game room...Let it be. If it was in the White House or fancy man cave....Fix it.